# How to find the inverse of a series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, inverse

Imagine a series like $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } f_n(x)$. Is there any formula to find the $f^{-1}(x)$ as series expansion like $f^{-1}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } g_n(x)$? Actually the the question is "How to find all of $g_n$ functions only using $f_n$ functions?"

For instance; $\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + ...$,  and $\arcsin(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{3x^5}{40} + \frac{5x^7}{112} + \frac{35x^9}{1152} ... $

Of course we have a lot of information about $\sin(x)$. But what if the given function is a very custom function? For example how to find the inverse of this kind of function:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{11n+5}}{(3n+2)!}$$

In general, if $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } f_n(x)$, I am searching for an operator, $\text{Inv}[f_0, f_1, f_2, ... ] = [g_0, g_1, g_2, ...]$ such that $f^{-1}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } g_n(x)$.

Comment: Power series inversion is a relatively easy process. If the series involves a sequence of arbitrary functions instead of monomial powers i.e. not a power series, a general procedure would not exist.

Comment: The [Lagrange inverson formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) might be of interest for you.

Comment: Does $f_n(x)$ mean a series term or $a_n\cdot x^n$?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash no it can be anything.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you mean the inverse in the multiplicative or bijective sense? In other words is it $$f^{-1} = \frac{1}{f}$$ or $$y=f(x) \iff x = f^{-1}(y)$$?

Comment: @Stef Given the presence of arcsin, I believe we can assume the bijective sense.

Answer (score 5):

I will explain how this works with an example, namely $\sin x = x-x^3/6\pm\cdots$.

Write $y=\sin x$ so that

$$y = x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}\pm\cdots$$

We seek a formula $x=$ power series in $y$.

First, compute some powers of $y$.

\begin{align*}
y^2&=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\frac{2x^6}{45}\pm\cdots\\
y^3&=x^3-\frac{x^5}{2}\pm\cdots\\
&\qquad\qquad\vdots
\end{align*}
which I get by squaring/cubing/etc the series for $y$ above.

Now, by making a linear combination of these powers of $y$, we can eliminate the powers of $x$ on the RHS. First, the $x^3$-term is removed by taking $y+y^3/6$:

$$y+\frac{y^3}{6}=x-\frac{3x^5}{40}\pm\cdots$$

If we keep eliminating powers of $x$ on the RHS, we are left with $x$ alone, so

$$x=\sin^{-1} y=y+\frac{y^3}{6}\pm...$$

---

*Remark.*

This method works for a power series $f(x)=\sum_{i>0} a_ix^i$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=a_1\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks, this method can form the basis of a good algorithm.

Comment: @MetehanTuran In some of those volumes titled something like "Tables of Integrals and Series", there are explicit formulas for the first several coefficients  of the inverse series, in terms of coefficients of the series which one seeks the inverse function for.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{11n+5}}{(3n+2)!}$$ By the way
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3 x^{7/3}}\left(e^{x^{11/3}}-2 e^{-\frac{x^{11/3}}{2}} \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{6} \left(3 \sqrt{3} x^{11/3}+\pi
   \right)\right)\right)$$

Since we know all coefficients, it is sufficient to use  the explicit formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term as given by Morse and Feshbach in year $1953$.

This could give for the inverse series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \,a_n\,t^{n+11}\qquad \text{with}\qquad t= \sqrt[5]{2x}$$ the very first coefficients being
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{300},\frac{367}{2520000},\frac{232339}{249480
   00000},\frac{3431}{4892160000},\frac{31409801191}{5427359437
   50000000}\right\}$$

Comment: How do you derive the explicit formula? The formula is very strange and complex, so I can't imagine that it's obvious.